# How to copy a table cell with shading color in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

When copied, the pasted value of the source cell is only the cell's text; the shading color is dropped.

How would I copy a cell with its shading color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Via hotkey

Paste by `Ctrl-V`, open paste options by `Alt-Shift-F10`, and `E` for Entire Cell.

### Via GUI

After you have copied the cells, make sure you right click where you want to place the cells and click on 'Paste Special..' and then pick an option to `paste all` e.g. `Entire Cell`, `Overwrite Cell` as below snapshots.

The cells will then be copied including the colour.

[image]

[image]

Comment: By the way, is there any way to pick 'Entire Cell' as default paste option? I posted this here http://superuser.com/questions/794080/how-to-set-a-specific-table-cells-paste-option-to-be-the-default-paste-behavior

Comment: Is there a way to copy shading only, without cell values? In particular, where shading has more than one colour, say, each cell has different colour. Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

The above does not apply in MS 2010. The quickest way to copy cells / rows which have shading in a table in MS Word 2010 is to (1) select all the cells / rows you want to copy (including the shaded cells / rows, which might be randomly shaded or, say, shaded in every second cell / row, or whatever), then (2) go to the position you want to paste from, then (3) right-click Paste Options' then (4) immediately under that click the THIRD icon along, which is to 'Insert As New Rows'. The cells will be copied, and for some mysterious reason will include their shading. Makes life easy if wanting to copy a stack of cells / rows that are shaded say every second row.
Hope this works for you, it does for me. Allen